# Make watchman check periodically for changes in a directory

Tags: watchman

I want to make watchman check for changes in a directory every  1 s or so. How can I do that. I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Watchman's purpose is to avoid needing to do such polls. You can just make a Watchman subscription to watch a directory for changes: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/subscribe.html